# Need a time object in one of my iOS app (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently creating an app where I ask the user to input a time (through datePicker) and send the user a notification every day on that time.
However, I noticed that datePicker only has an NSDate object, and was wondering if there was a Time object counterpart.
Also, would this Time object be a good way of storing the time, or should I convert the hour and minutes to Integers for storage?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDate also contains Time information within it. You can store the exact date and time using only NSDate. 
NSDate is a generic representation independent of any time zone. According to the apple docs:

> NSDate objects encapsulate a single point in time, independent of any particular calendrical system or time zone. Date objects are immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001)

NSDate is basically the number of seconds from the reference date mentioned above.

And yes NSDate is the best way for storing time and date information in your app.

Whenever you want to display the time, use NSDateFormatter to format the date and time into any format you desire and for any Time Zone you require.

**Swift 3**

The NSDate class has been renamed to Date in Swift 3

Comment: +1 because I was about to answer with basically the same text. Also, as a sidenote, if using Swift 3 NSDate is now Date.

Comment: @Dallas, haven't started with swift 3 yet so wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the info though, I'll make the edit